# windows phone application development for windows phone 8 and 10

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I want to develop windows application that runs on windows phone 8 and 10 both.

my dependency is only on windows phone not for desktop.

I have already developed an application that runs on win7,win8,win10 OS PC using C# and Xaml.

Now I have to develop the single application for windows phone 8 and windows phone 10   using C# and Xaml.

can i reuse the code that i wrote for windows desktop appliaction??

Can anyone guide me what is the minimum system requirement and how to proceed.

I read about windows 10 UWP app but this does not run on windows 8 phone.

please guide me.

Answer (score 1):

Windows Phone is totally different from traditional windows applications. Windows phone applications have a limit on API usages.

**Targeted Platform**

Since you want the app to run on both windows phone 8 and windows 10, try to target your app to windows phone 8 as this will run both on windows phone 8, windows phone 8.1 and windows 10 as well.

**Reusing the code**

If your desktop application is using an MVVM design pattern, you can use most of the code of the VM and Models in your Windows Phone 8 applications. However, you will have to work on the UI again for windows phone 8.